# How to fix this 2 issue by php (edit user from admin)?

Tags: php

Currently: user can be changed through admin and a problem comes if I empty the pass form... a new hashed pass is saved in the database and the user can no longer login with the old pass... where as pass form was blank.

So I need to fix these two issues....

How do I do that ?

1) Username cant be change by admin through admin panel. 
2) If Password form empty, hashed password will not change to database auto .

```
<?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //collect form data
    extract($_POST);

    //very basic validation
    if($username ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the username.';
    }

    if( strlen($password) > 0){

        if($password ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please enter the password.';
        }

        if($passwordConfirm ==''){
            $error[] = 'Please confirm the password.';
        }

        if($password != $passwordConfirm){
            $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
        }

    }


    if($email ==''){
        $error[] = 'Please enter the email address.';
    }

    if(!isset($error)){

        try {

            if(isset($password)){

                $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

                //update into database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_members SET username = :username, password = :password, email = :email WHERE memberID = :memberID') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':memberID' => $memberID
                ));


            } else {

                //update database
                $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE blog_members SET username = :username, email = :email WHERE memberID = :memberID') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':email' => $email,
                    ':memberID' => $memberID
                ));

            }


            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: users.php?action=updated');
            exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

}

?>


<?php
//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo $error.'<br />';
    }
}

    try {

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT memberID, username, email FROM blog_members WHERE memberID = :memberID') ;
        $stmt->execute(array(':memberID' => $_GET['id']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>

<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='memberID' value='<?php echo $row['memberID'];?>'>

    <p><label>Username</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo $row['username'];?>'></p>

    <p><label>Password (only to change)</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='password' value=''></p>

    <p><label>Confirm Password</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='passwordConfirm' value=''></p>

    <p><label>Email</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='email' value='<?php echo $row['email'];?>'></p>

    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update User'></p>

</form>
```

Comment: you're checking if the password is set in the first query but not in the `else`

Comment: trim your values before testing i.e. if( trim($username)=="" )

Comment: you should also use `!empty()` for the password rather than `isset()`, IMHO.

Comment: if the user has not completed the signup form correctly why enter anything at all into the database? if all requirements met - entry else back to form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make username field readonly. For second check below code.

```
If (empty($password))
{
  //update rest of info using query and skip password updation
}

else
{
  //update everything including password
}
```

Comment: readonly can be used its nice but i did it different way... but for 2nd issue ... i dont need required .... i need to fix it through php function

Comment: @Addons Check my edit and if it works please select it as answer.

Comment: thanks bro problem solved. also thanks to Fred -ii- he was also correct but i did not understand his comment at first.